# Spark withColumn null default value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to add a new String column to a dataframe with a default value of null (a non-null value will be applied later)

Here is my code

```
.withColumn("column-name", lit(null: String))
```

This creates a column with the Void type which I do not want

What is the easiest way to create a column of type String with null default value?

Note, the structure of the set of jobs is set in stone, and I am leaving this company very soon, so I am not interesting in arguing that the code should be restructured, I just want to give them the code they have asked for with the least fuss

Note also we aren't using a code-defined schema anywhere, it is pure schema inference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lit` with `null`, then cast it to your desired type.

`Example`

```
df.withColumn("test", lit(null).cast(StringType))
```

`Output`

```
+---+----+
|id |test|
+---+----+
|1  |null|
|2  |null|
|3  |null|
+---+----+
```

`Schema`

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- test: string (nullable = true)
```

Good luck!

Comment: oh god, that's simple, I will report back soon